# Run a function when closing google popup extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an alarm function in my extension, but when I close it I want it to clear the alarms, how can I do that?

Basically when I start my alarm, even when the extension is closed it will try to trigger the alarm function.

background.js:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("/popups/popup.html"),
        type: "popup",
        width: 350,
        height: 480
    },(win)=>{
        chrome.storage.local.set({'winId': win.id});
    })
});


chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async function(alarm) {
    let teste
    await chrome.storage.local.get(['winId']).then((result) => {
        teste = result.winId;
    });
    chrome.windows.update(teste, {focused: true});
});
```

I thought it would have some google.onclosed function, but I didn't find something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use chrome.storage.**session** not chrome.storage.**local** to store `winId`
2. use [chrome.windows.onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onRemoved) event in the background script

```js
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(async id => {
  const {winId} = await chrome.storage.session.get('winId');
  if (winId === id) {
    chrome.alarms.clearAll();
  }
}, ['popup']); // filtering by popups because our window was created with type: 'popup'
```